# How can I conditionally include a LESS file with django-compressor?

Tags: django-compressor

I'd like to conditionally import a LESS file inside a `{% compress css %}` block like this:

```
{% compress css %}
  <link href="{{ STATIC_URL }}common/css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  {% ifequal app "custom" %}
    <link href="{{STATIC_URL}}custom/less/style.less" rel="stylesheet" type="text/less">
  {% endifequal %}
{% endcompress %}
```

I'm using offline compressions and getting an `OfflineGenerationError`, which makes sense, I just don't know how to go about fixing it.

I have a couple ideas:

1. move the logic of the import into a view and server one html file for the include and one without
2. move the logic into css (if/how this is possible)
3. provide a conditional include, which compresses the LESS file
4. remove compress and compile the LESS file to CSS, then the above code should work

Thanks,

Aleck

Comment: Could you wrap this in two separate compress tags?

Comment: It works with online compression.

Answer (score 0):

Have you remembered to set the [COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT setting, as documented here](http://django-compressor.readthedocs.org/en/latest/settings/#django.conf.settings.COMPRESS_OFFLINE_CONTEXT)?

This is "the context to be used by the compress management command when rendering the contents of `{% compress %}` template tags and saving the result in the offline cache".

Since you're accessing the `app` context variable it could be what you need.